# vba loop to copy and paste to a specific cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA. The idea is that the loop should bring up each cell once during the process in column A into cell "B1".

What it does now, it copies data into column to the right, but I would like it to go up to to the top.

The code does this right now.
It moves content of A1 to B1, A2 to B2, A3 to B3, etc. The idea is to get the following: A1 to B1, A2 to B1, A3 to B1, A4 to B1, etc.

```
Sub StartLoop()
Application.Goto Reference:="StartLoop"
Do Until AciveCell = ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select 'range "A2:A2000" contains the data to test
Loop
End Sub
Sub copyLoop() 'copy from columnn A and past to a fix destination
Application.Goto Reference:="StartLoop"
    Do Until ActiveCell = ""
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select
Loop
    Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
End Sub>
```

Comment: It's not clear from your description what you're trying to achieve. Posting one or more screen shots might help, along with some sample code showing what you've already tried, i.e., the code that isn't working the way you want it to. (stackoverflow's [code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) is really quite good, and developers like to see _code_.)

Comment: Do you simply want to *transpose* the column to a row? Copy the entire data and pasteSpecial transpose it. Use the macro recorder to see how this can be done.

Comment: Hi David, indeed I did that but the way my macro starts it wont work from what I learnt in the macro recorder. What I am trying to do is to automate a copy past process whereby a1 goes to b1, a2 goes to b1, a3 goes to b1. b1 is linked to a data provider and it updates some info which the second part of the macro will export.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are just trying to loop through a column of values and paste each one into the same cell in turn. The following code would be a way to accomplish this.

```
Sub LoopTheStuff()
Dim columnA As Range
Dim target As Range

Set columnA = Range("A1:A" & ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row) 'selects range of A1 to the last cell with value
Set target = Range("B1")
For Each c In columnA
    target = c 'B1 = Ax
Next c

End Sub
```